# psql one to many join filter

Tags: postgresql, filter, inner-join, one-to-many, entity-attribute-value

Trying to do something on the lines of:

```
Table Entities

id |  timestamp
---------------
1  | 2012-06-05 12:00:00

Table Attributes

entity_id | attribute
---------------------
1         |   a
1         |   b
```

What i'd like to be able to do:

```
select entity.id, entity.timestamp from entities entity join attributes on entity.id = attribute.id where entity.has.attributes a and b
```

The result set would look woeful now, but assume it has other columns on the entities table that will make sense. So the result set would be:

```
id | timestamp
--------------
1  | 2012-06-05 12:00:00
```

I looked at other posts on filtering one-many join relationships that end up using a count and distinct to solve very specific niche cases ([Filter a one-to-many query by requiring all of many meet criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481588/filter-a-one-to-many-query-by-requiring-all-of-many-meet-criteria)) but I am hoping there's a cleaner, more generic solution to this.

Going to continue working away and I'll post back a solution if I can beat stackoverflow to it :)

Comment: It appears that you are using an entity-attribute-value variant table design. You're unlikely to find anything pretty or performant; EAV is generally considered an anti-pattern because it's horrible to use and performs badly. It has its uses, but it should really be a last resort.

Comment: curiously, you are right. i am (strongly against my will) trying to emulate a more...mellow version of the EAV; thing being, the attributes DO form a sparse matrix for me and my entities are quite varying. the table is a one-size-fit-all for multiple objects - think reporting on recruitment, promotions and ad campaigns all living in the same table to be plotted on a heatmap for example.

Comment: Sounds like you might be doing datamining/analytics; have you looked into star schema?

Comment: You can find a lot of good general information and pointers for [**EAV** under this related question on dba.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20759/is-there-a-name-for-this-database-structure)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have working so far. As pointed out, it's not pretty and I would daresay not performant, but I am going to look into full text search indices to see what they can offer.

```
select e.id, e.timestamp from entities e join 
    (select entity_id, string_agg(attribute, ',' order by attribute) as attr from attributes 
     group by entity_id) a 
on e.id = a.entity_id where a.attr like '%a%b%';
```

But this assumes that you have the order by clause in the aggregation. If you choose to leave that out, this should work:

```
select e.id, e.timestamp from entities e join 
    (select entity_id, string_agg(attribute, ',') as attr from attributes 
     group by entity_id) a 
on e.id = a.entity_id where a.attr like '%a%' and a.attr like '%b%';
```

Very brittle, will break if your search attributes have kangaroo-word-like relationships. But, this will have to do for now.